# css id selector vs element id selector to control style via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, styles

in my code there's a css style Settings for all table headers - `<th>`

i did not make settings for Css my self but until now it was ok for me so i didn't try to edit those .

but now that i have to print the page, and  font color set to `#ffffff`
it sure looks nice on a backGround but on print out it will not show

my css is made out like this

```
    #TBLtime th , #TBLparam1 th , #TBLparam2 th
    {
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color:#A7C942;
    color:#ffffff;
    }
```

so id selector is per element , how do you make it easier to control /modify from javascript

say i need to alter color property . how will i be able to access it from javascript ?

```
    function DocPrnt() {
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
        print();
    }
```

is there a better option for a selector to be easy to access from JS or this is common approach ?

Comment: Why don't you use a different print style sheet?

Comment: @Tariqulazam i could have tried that too(for future use) sounds good , though here it's only that th color and problem solved

Comment: Even if it is for a single element, I would have used the print style sheet to save some time in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a pure JavaScript solution, this may work:

```
function DocPrnt() {
    var headerCells = [],
        i = 0;
    headerCells = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
    for (i = 0; i < headerCells.length; i += 1) {
        headerCells[i].style.color = "#000000";
    }
    print();
}
```

Personally, I'd just add a new stylesheet for printing only:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: looks good from here , thanks for a quick reply . for now i think i will just use the js and for future reference , how will your code inside print.css will look or its same as default CSS code with different values , but what is controling the whole idea set one for display then another for print ? or set default maybe one of the option is as in my example for display , and then comes your `<link rel...>` to declare a printout setting ?

Comment: @LoneXcoder: The `media` attribute is what the browser uses to determine the rendering device. `media="all"` is good for all devices, `media="print"` is good for print devices, `media="screen"` is good for monitors (etc.). The CSS inside "print.css" is just normal CSS, although you can try for paged media using `@page` rules. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/ is a really good article about this.

Comment: thanks for info i will now edit your Code if you don't mind pete (gonna have a look at your link) thanks man